# Mutate subscript out of bounds

Tags: dplyr

I am trying to create a summary table  of sensitivity and specificity from two caret model outputs and in my for loop it's throwing a subscript out of bounds error when looking up the values from the list called models containing the values? Here is a fully reproducible example. Dplyr is version 0.7.0. Thanks.

```
heart <- read.table("http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/datasets/SAheart.data",
       sep=",",head=T,row.names=1)

library(car)

heart$chd <- factor(car::recode(heart$chd, "c(1)='Yes'; 
else='No'"), levels = c('Yes', 'No'))

library(caret)

set.seed(42)
index <- createDataPartition(heart$chd, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
train_data <- heart[index, ]
test_data  <- heart[-index, ]
set.seed(42)
model_rf <- caret::train(chd ~ .,
                     data = train_data,
                     method = "rf",
                     trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                                              number = 10, 
                                              repeats = 10, 
                                              verboseIter = FALSE))
final <- data.frame(actual = test_data$chd,
                predict(model_rf, newdata = test_data, type = "prob"))
final$predict <- factor(ifelse(final$Yes > 0.5, "Yes", "No"), levels = c('Yes', 'No'))
cm_original <- confusionMatrix(final$predict, test_data$chd)


# down sampling
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                 number = 10, 
                 repeats = 10, 
                 verboseIter = FALSE,
                 sampling = "down")

set.seed(42)
model_rf_under <- caret::train(chd ~ .,
                     data = train_data,
                     method = "rf",

                     trControl = ctrl)

final_under <- data.frame(actual = test_data$chd,
                predict(model_rf_under, newdata = test_data, type = "prob"))
final_under$predict <- factor(ifelse(final_under$Yes > 0.5, "Yes", "No"), levels = c('Yes', 'No'))
cm_down <- confusionMatrix(final_under$predict, test_data$chd)


models <- list(original = model_rf,
           under = model_rf_under
           )

library(dplyr)
comparison <- data.frame(model = names(models),
                     Sensitivity = rep(NA, length(models)),
                     Specificity = rep(NA, length(models))
                      )

for (name in names(models)) {
model <- get(paste0("cm_", name))

comparison[comparison$model == name, ] <- filter(comparison, model == 
name) %>% mutate( Sensitivity = model[['byClass']][['Sensitivity']],
                 Specificity = model[['byClass']][['Specificity']]  )

}

comparison
```

Comment: I'm getting a different error, where is your error occurring?

Comment: fixed the code a bit, was missing mutate next to the %>% in the for loop. the error occurs just before the final line with the call to comparison. Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: subscript out of bounds.

Comment: You don't have the manually convert the probabilities to classes with `type = "prob"`. Just use `predict` without that option.

Comment: You would also be better off comparing the models using the resampling results rather than going to the test set. See `resamples`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer to this but just in case someone comes across this.

I Came across the similar issue. Error in spite of `mutate` after the pipe.

Alternatively i used `mutate_()` which fixed the problem.

```
filter(comparision, model == name) %>% 
 mutate_(Sensitivity = model[["byClass"]][['Sensitivity']],
 Specificity = model[["byClass"]][['Specificity']])
```

Comment: Thank you. what is the major difference between mutate and mutate_?

Comment: @Drendar It just uses standard evaluation. Although sparingly used these days.