# x subscript out of bounds in mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I am recoding a variable in my data and I keep running into an "x subscript out of bounds" error when I run my code. I think I could probably get this to recode another way, but I've used this method in the past and I'd like to know why it isn't working now. Another post ([Dplyr - Mutate subscript out of bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44684472/dplyr-mutate-subscript-out-of-bounds/52076896)) described getting this error with a mutate function, like I am, and solved it by using mutate_, but that has since been depreciated.

I have (poorly) made a an example of my data and my code:

```
data.frame(school = c("HS", "AS", "BS", "HS", "AS", "BS", "HS", "AS", "AS", "NOPE", "NOPE", NA, NA, NA, NA),
       id = c(1:15)) -> t
library(dplyr)
t %>% 
  mutate(school = case_when(school == "HS" ~ 4,
                        school == "AS" ~ 5,
                        school == "BS" ~ 6,
                        school== "NOPE" ~ 10,
                                  TRUE ~ NULL)) %>% 
select(school) %>% 
summary()
```

Running this code produces the error. Do you have any ideas as to why this isn't working? I apologize if it's something really obvious. I've been staring at it for a while.

Comment: You can't put NULL values in a vector. If you just leave the `TRUE~NULL` part out, it will work fine (the default is to return NA). If you want to be explicit, use `TRUE ~ NA_real_`

Comment: This answers my question. Thank you!